# .setInterval() and Drupal.attachBehaviors are causing my js file to run multiple instances

Tags: jquery, drupal-6

I am delivering ajax content to a page and I need to reattach Drupal behaviors to that content.  I am using the following jquery.  The code polls the server every 5 seconds for data and displays it.

```
Drupal.behaviors.god_geo = function(context) {
setInterval("god_geo_event()", 5000);  // call god_geo_event() every 5 seconds
};

/**
* A Function to fetch quotes from the server and display in the designated
* area.
*/
function god_geo_event(){
$.getJSON(Drupal.settings.god_geo.json_url, function(data)  {
  if(!data.status || data.status == 0)  {
      $("#god_geo_occupants-text").html(data.event.occupants);
      Drupal.attachBehaviors("#god_geo_occupants-text");   //THIS CRASHES BROWSER.
  }
}); //end inline function.
```

When I try to add Drupal.attachBehaviors(), it appears to be relaunching new instances of my JS file.    When I look in firebug, I see a new instance of my js file running, then 4, then 8, then 16, then 32.  Before long, I have 100's of if the same .js file running and of course, the browser locks up.  Thank you greatly for any insights.

Comment: I think I have it. Simply answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've solved your own problem.

Side note (too messy for a comment): please don't pass strings to `setTimeout` and `setInterval`; it's `eval` in disguise. Pass the function itself:

```
setInterval(god_geo_event, 5000);
```

or pass an anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function ()
{
    god_geo_event();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the answer will be that the function called by setInterval has (), when it should not. 
    setInterval("god_geo_event()", 5000);

should be.

```
setInterval("god_geo_event", 5000);
```

We are not passing the results to setInterval, we are passing the function call.  Still need to test but I think this is the problem that has eluded hundreds on 3 different boards for thre three months.. Amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you call your function in the #document context.

```
Drupal.behaviors.god_geo = function(context) {
  setInterval(function () {
    if ($(context).length && $(context)[0].nodeName == '#document') {
      god_geo_event();
    }
  }, 5000); 
};
```